# MongoDB - How to $inc in a double nested array

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm trying to increment `c` every time a user choose a label.

My sample dataset has two nested arrays:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "labels": [
        {
            "label": "orange",
            "hitCount": 2,
            "hits": [
                {
                    "who": "bob",
                    "c": "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "red",
            "hitCount": 6,
            "hits": [
                {
                    "who": "bob",
                    "c": "5"
                },
                {
                    "who": "alice",
                    "c": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For example `bob` choose again `red` so I want to increment the `c` inside bob's object inside red's object from 5 to 6.

I can't use `$` two times to navigate inside more than one array per https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays

So anyone knows how to traverse more than one level of array and obtain a reference for `$inc`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is currently possible, it's currently a JIRA item: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

You could consider using aggregation to get the results you'd like and using $out to update the collection, or you can consider changing your data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to change you data model to:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "labels": [
        {
            "label": "orange",
            "hitCount": 2,
            "hits": {
              "bob": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "red",
            "hitCount": 6,
            "hits": {
              "bob":5,
              "alice":1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you could update hits using this command:

```
db.hits.update(
    { 'labels.label': 'red' }, 
    { '$inc': { 'labels.$.hitCount': 1, 'labels.$.hits.bob': 1 } }
);
```

If you need to construct update with dynamic username, you can do it:

```
var userName = 'bob';
var updateCommand = {
  $inc: {
    'labels.$.hitCount': 1
  }
};
updateCommand.$inc['labels.$.hits.' + userName] = 1;

db.hits.update({ 'labels.label': 'red' },  updateCommand);
```